# Polynomial reduction of Hamiltonian path to cycle and cycle to path

Tags: algorithm, graph, hamiltonian-cycle

I need to show that given undirected graph G, Hamiltonian path and Hamiltonian cycle are polynomial time reducible to each other. Here is my reduction, is this correct?

For Cycle to Path
For a vertex v belonging to V, add a vertex v’ and for all e(v,u) add edge e(v’ ,u). Now if there is a Hamiltonian Path from v to v’, then there is a Hamiltonian cycle for v.

For Path to cycle
For a vertices s and t, for all edges e(t,u) add an edge e(s,u) (if this edge did not existed) and for all edges e(s,u) add an endge (t,u) (if this edge did not existed). Finally add an edge e(s,t). Now if there is a Hamiltonian cycle for s or t, then there is a Hamiltonian path from s to t.

Are there reductions correct ? also is this enough to show that these two problems are polynomial time reducible to each other ?

Comment: The second reduction is not obvious at all. Explain what you do with the cycle to obtain a path from s to t.

Comment: Well my thinking was to sort of collapse s and t into one vertex and if there is a cycle for this vertex then there is a path for original graph. I am not sure if this is a correct reduction, but I tried it on few examples and it seems correct.

Comment: A cycle is not guaranteed to pass through any of the added edges. If you want to collapse s and t into a new vertex, add a new vertex.

Comment: So for path to cycle reduction. If I add a new vertex v and add edges e(v,t) e(v,s) the cycle for this v will guarantee a path from s to t ?

Comment: Yes it will. A Hamiltonian cycle by definition passes through all vertices so you don't need to say "a cycle for v".

Comment: You can also try to find an easier cycle to path reduction. There is one that adds no new edges or vertices to the graph.

Comment: n.m. any clue where can I find info about this easier reduction ?

Comment: Come up with it yourself... btw, your reduction doesn't work for a graph with 2 vertices and 1 edge. Not a big problem, this is a special case that needs to be checked separately.